# amanda backup and take

Tags: backup, amanda

I'm very new to amanda-backup and also linux 
I'm looking for the amanda-backup setting

https://www.howtoforge.com/centralized-backup-server-with-amanda-on-centos

I saw the "tape(?)" setting in this tutorial

> 8. Create tape list:
>
> touch /etc/amanda/intra/tapelist  chown –R amanda:disk
>   /etc/amanda/intra
>
> 9. Create slots (virtual tapes):
>
> su - amanda  cd /backup/intra/slots for ((i=1; $i<=15; i++)); do mkdir
>   slot$i; done  ln -s slot1 data
>
> 10. Test virtual tapes:
>
> /usr/sbin/ammt -f file:/backup/intra/slots status

I guess my linux server does not have Tape thing

is take can be replace with file-server(NAS)??

if it is do I have to change the configuration of tape?

Answer (score 2):

Like many back-up solutions that evolved in the era when [magnetic tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_tape_data_storage) or [LTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_Tape-Open) were the principal  affordable bulk/archival storage media, amanda uses the same logic of tape drives, [tape libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_library) and tapes also for disk based storage by addressing that storage as a  *"fake/virtual"*  tapes.

That will use directories in your file system, so as long as your NAS is mounted amanda will backup to your NAS the same as it would to local disk based storage:  http://wiki.zmanda.com/index.php/How_To:Set_Up_Virtual_Tapes

Comment: Totally agree with what has been mentioned here, I have used VTL and really good.

Answer (score 0):

Amanda 3.5 Binaries are available in the following pages.

Source tarballs are available from

http://www.amanda.org
https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=120

Binaries for many systems are available from

http://www.zmanda.com/download-amanda.php

Documentation can be found at

http://wiki.zmanda.com

Here's a list of the changes for release 3.5 (from the NEWS file):
Look at the ReleaseNotes and ChangeLog file for more details.

Fix compilation on Solaris
Do not check all 'r' bit on suid binary
Fix parsing of configuration override (-o)
can unset some setting
client code will not fail if shared memory is not available
amreport
lot of improvement
allow '*' for a datestamp wildcard
amgetconf
print an empty string if a parameter is not set instead of 'no such parameter'
amdump
new --no-dump, --no-flush and --no-vault argument
amstatus fix
lock holding disk to protect multiple parallel access